# Position estimation for iOS using accelerometer

Tags: ios, matlab, position, accelerometer, kalman-filter

In iOS, it is easy to access Linear Acceleration which is equal to subtracting Gravity from Raw acceleration.

I am trying to estimate position by double integrating Linear Acceleration. For that I recorded the data by keeping the phone steady on table.

Then I did double integration in Matlab using `cumtrapz` but when I plot the position it grows with time.

What am I doing wrong? I was expecting that the position should be 0.

Comment: Most commercial accelerometers have **way too much** bias error and noise around the zero level to be used for this type of calculations. Only sensors **specifically designed** for inertial navigation will let you do that. Even then, this is often too noisy to be used alone so when possible it is used in conjunction with another position indicator (typically a GPS) and both data sets are merged/filtered using a Kalman filter.

Comment: Applications which use only inertial navigation need 6 axis sensors (3-axial accel and 3-axial gyro) to perform even half correctly ... These sensors are usually embedded with a hardware feedback compensation loop to de-noise and compensate error on the fly. Sensors capable of doing that start at $5,000 a pop (and can reach $20,000 easily). Not the typical accelerometer in your iPhone. Plus these type of sensors is what is used in ballistic and weaponry, so their distribution is quite restricted. If an iPhone had these capabilities, you could not sell iPhone as widely as it is now.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q_8d0E3tDk

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read this is too error-prone to be useful. Accelerometer based position calculations are subject to small drift errors, which accumulate over time. (If the phone is traveling at 100 kph constant velocity when your app first launches, you can't tell.) All you can measure is acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

There would always been biasing errors from the sensors which can grow with time while integration. Can you calculate the drift of sensor when the device is at rest?. And then try to take the mean of the drift and subtract it from the input so that sensor shows 0 at rest, Then try to double integrate it